# Summarizing Data in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data, table, summarizing

I need to summarize a set of incident data by several different stations. I have a set of five stations. The stations code emergency response using 10 incident codes, 1 being least severe and 10 being most.

I need to summarize the data so that each station has its own incident count, e.g., Station 1 had 34 incident 1 calls, 35 incident 2 calls, etc. Station 2 had 34 incident 1 calls, etc.

Essentially, I need to have a table output that has 5 rows and 10 sub-rows per main row. Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried Summary Statistics with two Case Fields?

Comment: I always use Excel pivot table to accomplish this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Summary Statistics](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00080000001z000000) tool is what you are looking for.

Use the case field to be the column that represents your data of interest.

Also, the tool provides the following option:

- SUM—Adds the total value for the specified field.

  - MEAN—Calculates the average for the specified field.
  - MIN—Finds the smallest value for all records of the specified field.
  - MAX—Finds the largest value for all records of the specified field.
  - RANGE—Finds the range of values (MAX minus MIN) for the specified field.
  - STD—Finds the standard deviation on values in the specified field.
  - COUNT—Finds the number of values included in statistical calculations. This counts each value except null values. To determine the number of null values in a field, use the COUNT statistic on the field in question, and a COUNT statistic on a different field which does not contain nulls (for example, the OID if present), then subtract the two values.
  - FIRST—Finds the first record in the Input Table and uses its specified field value.
  - LAST—Finds the last record in the Input Table and uses its specified field value.

[image]